# git lab integration with kubernate cluster with "Add existing kubernate cluster" option

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I'm trying to integrate a Kubernetes cluster into gitlab by using the `"Add existing Kubernetes cluster"` option. This integration is required to configure this cluster as a Runner in gitlab to execute the build.

Below details have been provided for the integration:

```
Kubernetes cluster name : kube_cluster
API URL : https://ipadress:port ex: https://10.8.9.0:8443
CA certificate:
CA certificate from kubernate cluster
Token: token obtained by below command
kubectl -o json get secret default-xxxxx-ght | jq -r '.data.token' | base64 -d > token.txt
```

but the integration fails during the Helm installation without a proper error message in git lab. How to solve this issue? Is there a way to find out what is actually failing in background?

Error message:

```
"Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller
Can't start installation process"
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to your Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

According to [their issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/48978#note_104709946), one needs to upgrade the GitLab version to v11.1 to work around that bug, although [another person](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/52108) is experiencing TLS weirdness after upgrading, so watch out for that, too